# Invalid JSON when attributesFormat=object is used in the tourguide

Tags: fiware-orion

We found an issue with `attributesFormat=object` while testing the tourguide application https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.TourGuide-App

If we perform the following request:

```
curl  <cb_host>:<cb_port>/v1/contextEntities/type/Restaurant/id/Elizalde -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'x-auth-token:<token>' --header 'Fiware-service: tourguide' --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

we get this valid JSON:

```
{
  "contextElement" : {
    "type" : "Restaurant",
    "isPattern" : "false",
    "id" : "Elizalde",
    "attributes" : [
      {
        "name" : "address",
        "type" : "",
        "value" : {
          "type" : "postalAddress",
          "streetAddress" : "Cuesta de las Cabras Aldapa 2",
          "addressRegion" : "Araba",
          "addressLocality" : "Alegría-Dulantzi",
          "postalCode" : "01240"
        }
      },
      {
        "name" : "aggregateRating",
        "type" : "",
        "value" : {
          "reviewCount" : 1,
          "ratingValue" : 3
        }
      },
      {
        "name" : "capacity",
        "type" : "PropertyValue",
        "value" : 120,
        "metadatas" : [
          {
            "name" : "name",
            "type" : "",
            "value" : "capacity"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name" : "department",
        "type" : "",
        "value" : "Franchise3"
      },
      {
        "name" : "description",
        "type" : "",
        "value" : "Restaurante de estilo sidrería ubicado en Alegria-Dulantzi. Además de su menú del día y carta, también ofrece menú de sidrería. El menú del día cuesta 9 euros. Los fines de semana la especialidad de la casa son las alubias con sacramentos. En lo que a bebidas se refiere, hay una amplia selección además de la sidra. Cabe destacar que se puede hacer txotx. La capacidad del establecimiento es de 50 personas pero la sidrería no dispone de aparcamiento.%5cn%5cnHORARIO: %5cn%5cnLunes a domingo: 9:00-17:00 y 19:00-23:00."
      },
      {
        "name" : "occupancyLevels",
        "type" : "PropertyValue",
        "value" : 0,
        "metadatas" : [
          {
            "name" : "timestamp",
            "type" : "",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "name",
            "type" : "",
            "value" : "occupancyLevels"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name" : "position",
        "type" : "coords",
        "value" : "42.8404625, -2.5123277",
        "metadatas" : [
          {
            "name" : "location",
            "type" : "string",
            "value" : "WGS84"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name" : "priceRange",
        "type" : "",
        "value" : 0
      },
      {
        "name" : "telephone",
        "type" : "",
        "value" : "945 400 868"
      }
    ]
  },
  "statusCode" : {
    "code" : "200",
    "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
  }
}
```

But if we use the attributesFormat=object:

```
curl  <cb_host>:<cb_port>/v1/contextEntities/type/Restaurant/id/Elizalde?attributesFormat=object -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'x-auth-token:<token>' --header 'Fiware-service: tourguide' --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

we get this invalid JSON:

```
{
    "contextElement": {
        "type": "Restaurant",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "Elizalde",
        "attributes": {
            "address": {
                "type": "",
                "value": {
                    "type": "postalAddress",
                    "streetAddress": "Cuesta de las Cabras Aldapa 2",
                    "addressRegion": "Araba",
                    "addressLocality": "Alegría-Dulantzi",
                    "postalCode": "01240"
                }
            },
            "aggregateRating": {
                "type": "",
                "value": {
                    "reviewCount": 1,
                    "ratingValue": 3
                }
            },
            "capacity": {
                "type": "PropertyValue",
                "120",
                "metadatas": [{
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "",
                    "value": "capacity"
                }]
            },
            "department": {
                "type": "",
                "value": "Franchise3"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "",
                "value": "Restaurante de estilo sidrería ubicado en Alegria-Dulantzi. Además de su menú del día y carta, también ofrece menú de sidrería. El menú del día cuesta 9 euros. Los fines de semana la especialidad de la casa son las alubias con sacramentos. En lo que a bebidas se refiere, hay una amplia selección además de la sidra. Cabe destacar que se puede hacer txotx. La capacidad del establecimiento es de 50 personas pero la sidrería no dispone de aparcamiento.%5cn%5cnHORARIO: %5cn%5cnLunes a domingo: 9:00-17:00 y 19:00-23:00."
            },
            "occupancyLevels": {
                "type": "PropertyValue",
                "0",
                "metadatas": [{
                    "name": "timestamp",
                    "type": "",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "",
                    "value": "occupancyLevels"
                }]
            },
            "position": {
                "type": "coords",
                "value": "42.8404625, -2.5123277",
                "metadatas": [{
                    "name": "location",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "WGS84"
                }]
            },
            "priceRange": {
                "type": "",
                "0"
            },
            "telephone": {
                "type": "",
                "value": "945 400 868"
            }
        }
    },
    "statusCode": {
        "code": "200",
        "reasonPhrase": "OK"
    }
}
```

Steps to replicate:

- Clone the tourguide repository.
- Deploy the docker containers: `cd fiware-devguide-app/docker/compose` and `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`
- Get token as explained here : https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.TourGuide-App#how-to-retrieve-an-oauth-token-to-use-the-api
- Perform the specified requests.

Information about orion version:

```
<orion>
   <version>0.28.0</version>
    <uptime>0 d, 1 h, 12 m, 25 s</uptime>
    <git_hash>aaf8020a5de680b6d7e0c00c70cf425bcc4f39c8</git_hash>
    <compile_time>Mon Mar 21 13:20:37 UTC 2016</compile_time>
    <compiled_by>root</compiled_by>
    <compiled_in>838a42ae8431</compiled_in>
</orion>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question post to add the Orion version you are using, please? I.e. `GET /version` on the Orion API. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug with `attributeFormat=object` rendering in Orion 0.28.0. The bug will be fixed for Orion 1.1.0, to be released by the end of April 2016 (it is about to be merged into develop branch right now, this is [the PR](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/2060) if you want to monitor progress).

Comment: Thank you, we will keep an eye on the PR.

Comment: Please remember to upvote and aprove the answer (not only to feed my ego ;), but also to make clear to other users that this answer is correct).